# Getting wrong records count from my mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

[image]I know I am doing something wrong here but I couldn't figure out where ?
Trying to display records and delete them by clicking on a Remove button, records get displayed but they are duplicates eventhough in my Table they are unique, here is my code:

```php
// Fech files and display them in a Modal        
        if($_POST["action"] == "fetch_files")
                {
                $file_data = scandir($_POST["folder_name"]);
                ?>
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr style="background-color:#FFC300">   
            <th style="text-align: left">Document Name</th>
            <!-- <th style="text-align: center">Category</th> -->
            <th style="text-align: right">Remove Document</th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
foreach($file_data as $file)
{
    $records = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from files"); // fetch data from database
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
    {   
        if($file === '.' or $file === '..')
        {
            continue;
        }
                        
        else
        {
            $path = $_POST["folder_name"] . '/' . $file;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td data-folder_name="<?php echo $_POST["folder_name"]; ?>"  data-file_name = "<?php echo  $file; ?>" class="change_file_name"><?php echo $file; ?></td>
                <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" button name="remove_file" class="remove_file btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right" id="<?php echo $path; ?>">Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: How many items are in `$file_data`? Your code will repeat all the records in your database that many times (because the code to get all the records in the database is within the code which loops through `$file_data`). It's not really clear what you're expecting the code to do though...is there maybe meant to be a link between individual files, and individual rows in the database table?

Comment: No there isn't that's just formatting issue.. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: I added $file_data which is the number of pdf files in a directory if that helps ?

Comment: The idea here is to delete records (pdf files) from both mysql Table and the folder, but need to fix duplicates first.

Comment: Well that proves my point, yes. But in terms of solving your problem, first we need to understand your intent. What exactly are you wanting to display? Currently you're indiscriminately mangling together a list of files in a folder with a list of records from a database. Is there supposed to be some sort of logical connection between individual files and individual database rows, perhaps? Some sample source data (from the folder and the database) and a sample of the expected output from this bit of code would go a long way to clarifying your scenario, I think.

Comment: `if($file === '.' or $file === '..')` should be in the `foreach` loop, since it's the same for every row in the query results.

Comment: If all the files in your folder are already listed in your database then there's probably no need to scan the folder, you could just list all the items from the database alone. But I don't know that for sure because as I've just mentioned, I can't see your data and I don't 100% know what exactly you're wanting to output.

Comment: You're multiplying the files in `$file_data` by every row in the table. Each Delete button will delete a different `$data['id']`, but there's no way to tell which ID it's going to delete, because you label them all with the same filename.

Comment: @ADyson
Yes, Thank you, what I an doing here is uploading PDf files to a folder and inserting some data like name, Category etc, so when I need to delete a file I can delete it both from its folder and its record in the table.. right now I can do that, but I need to only display unique records, no duplicates... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect what you need to do is make an associative array from the table data, that maps filenames to ID. Then you can use `$array[$file]['id']` as the ID in the `delete.php` URL.

Comment: Is the path and/or name of the file stored in the database table too? If not then you have no way to link the file to the database entry, so you can't really achieve your goal. But if so then there is no need to scan the folder or have the outer `foreach` loop, as I already talked about earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I finally kept loop (foreach($file_data as $file) as I needed it to unlink. here is a working code that deletes files out of folder and deleted them from the table as well. THANK YOU All.

```
        <?php 
        foreach($file_data as $file)
        {
        if($file === '.' or $file === '..')
        {   
        continue;
        }
        else
        {
        $path = $_POST["folder_name"] . '/' . $file;
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $file; ?></td>
        <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $file; ?>" button name="remove_file" class="remove_file btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right" id="<?php echo $path; ?>">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        }
        }

        //The UNLINK portion:

        if($_POST["action"] == "remove_file")
        {
        if(file_exists($_POST["path"]))
        {
        $path = $_POST["folder_name"] . '/' . $file;
        unlink($_POST["path"]);     
        //echo "<script>alert('Your document has been Deleted Successfully !');</script>";
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                 
        }
        }

        //Delete.php file:

        include "config.php"; // Using database connection file here

        $id = $_GET['id']; // get id through query string

        $del = mysqli_query($conn,"delete from files where name = '$id'"); // delete query

        if($del)
        {
        mysqli_close($conn); // Close connection
        header("location:home.php"); // redirects to all records page
        exit;   
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Error deleting record"; // display error message if not delete
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have double Loop.

```
foreach($file_data as $file)
{
    $records = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from files"); // fetch data from database
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
    {
```

You can remove `foreach` loop and just list files from database, As ADyson said, you need to have file_name in you db table column, then you can send file_name as param to delete.php

in `delete.php` have something like this

```
  $sql = "DELETE FROM files WHERE file_name=$GET['file_name']";
  unlink($path.$GET['file_name']);
  //redirect to files
```

Comment: I did remove the first loop, now records show uo normal, but I can't UNLINK the file from its folder !
I use:
unlink($_POST["path"]);

Comment: can you echo $_POST["path"] to see if there is really the path of file. it should be relative to this php file or full Absolute path to that file

Comment: I will try to use your code and see . thank you.

Comment: it is not unlinking, after a removed the other loop, Unlink code stopped working...

Comment: show the code of delete.php and folder structire where files are